# Sitecore global header

Tags: .net, content-management-system, sitecore

Just wondering what the best practice is to set a global header that can be overridden on certain pages if may need be?

For example there is google tracking code applied globally (to the whole site) and on one form it needs to have its own tracking code and the global one removed?

I have tried creating a code block and setting the standard values in the Item Template although only applies the code to a newly created page but does not apply to existing pages. This would mean that one would have to add the code to each individual page.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I have had to implement solutions such as this I would either create a template called 'Site settings' and inherit it from the homepage (or create a item using this template) and then write some extension methods for the Site class. Storing the ID of the settings item in the Web.config is something I usually prefer to avoid to I usually just attach the template to the homepage.

That way I can end up with the following.

```
<%=Sitecore.Context.Site.Settings.AnalyticsCode()%>
```

This particular extension method would first look at the context item to see if the 'Analytics code' field is populated, if it is not then I grab the homepage and get the field from there instead.

This method of course allows you to expand with a number of handy extension methods available from your context site or context item.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a kind of setting item in the Sitecore tree with the field and add that field to the selected pages as well. Then use the code similar to this:

```
<%= (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sitecore.Context.Item["GoogleId"]))
    ? Sitecore.Context.Item["GoogleId"] 
    : MySettingsItem["GoogleId"] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a decent usage of "Field Fallback." Essentially, each page (Item) in your site would have the `Google Tracking Code` field. You would wire up some sort of Fallback mechanism to use the value on the current item, or look up the tree until you find a value. This would allow you to set the `Google Tracking Code` at the 'Home' item and all descendants would use the value, unless it was explicitly set at a lower level.

See [my (Sean Kearney's) blog post](http://seankearney.com/post/Sitecore-Content-Fallback-and-the-Field-Fallback-Module.aspx) on the subject of fallback.

Here is a link to my [Field Fallback shared source module](http://trac.sitecore.net/FieldFallback).